# Prove that if the complete graph $K_n$ can be decomposed into triangles

Tags: graph-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if the complete graph $K_n$ can be decomposed into triangles (i.e., there is a set of subgraphs of $K_n$ such that each subgraph is isomorphic to $K_3$, and each edge of $K_n$ appears in exactly one of the triangles), then $n - 1$ or $n - 3$ is divisible by $6$. Find an explicit decomposition to triangles of $K_7$ and $K_9$. (Hint: number the vertices, and provide only the triples of the decompositions.)

Comment: What have you tried?  At a minimum you need the number of edges of $K_n$ to be divisible by $3$ and the number of edges at each vertex to be even (Why?).

Answer (score 2):

> **Hint.** If a triangular decomposition exists, then
>
> 1. the number of edges of $K_n$ must be divisible by $3$ (why?), and
> 2. the degree of each vertex in $K_n$ is even (why?).

> Proving the hints: (1) each edge of $K_n$ appears in exactly one of the triangles (2) for a given vertex, each triangle either contains $0$ or $2$ of its edges.

> The first fact implies $n(n-1)$ is divisible by $3$. The second fact implies $n$ is odd. If $n-1$ is divisible by $3$, then the fact that $n-1$ is also even implies $n-1$ is divisible by $6$. Otherwise $n$ is divisible by $3$; use the fact that $n$ is odd to conclude that $n-3$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: I can't understand (2) . Also I can't understand why it would imply n is odd. Please help me.

Comment: Proving (2): For a given vertex, each triangle contributes either $0$ or $2$ edges to that vertex, so that vertex's degree must be even. Proving that (2) implies $n$ is odd: remind yourself that we are considering the graph $K_n$ (what are the degrees of its vertices?). @PritamRoy